# javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send to a non-connected transport

Tags: java, jms, qpid

I am using the `qpid-jms-client.jar` library to form a connection with a broker.

My code is ::

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("jndi.properties"));
Context context = new InitialContext(properties);

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/Users/xxxxx/qpid.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "test123");

ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("myFactoryLookup");
Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("myQueueLookup");
Connection connection = factory.createConnection("<my-username>", "<my-password>");
connection.setExceptionListener(new MyExceptionListener());
connection.start();
```

My jndi.properties file is ::

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory
connectionfactory.myFactoryLookup=amqps://esesslx0100.se:9443
queue.myQueueLookup=emft_input
topic.myTopicLookup=topic
destination.topicExchange=amq.topic
jms.user=test
```

Now the above code gives me the ERROR ::

```
Connection ExceptionListener fired, exiting.
javax.jms.JMSException: Cannot send to a non-connected transport.
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:66)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.exceptions.JmsExceptionSupport.create(JmsExceptionSupport.java:88)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.onAsyncException(JmsConnection.java:1188)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.onConnectionFailure(JmsConnection.java:1104)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.fireProviderException(AmqpProvider.java:847)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.pumpToProtonTransport(AmqpProvider.java:820)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.access$300(AmqpProvider.java:90)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider$16.run(AmqpProvider.java:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot send to a non-connected transport.
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty.NettyTcpTransport.checkConnected(NettyTcpTransport.java:279)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.transports.netty.NettyTcpTransport.allocateSendBuffer(NettyTcpTransport.java:176)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.amqp.AmqpProvider.pumpToProtonTransport(AmqpProvider.java:806)
    ... 9 more
```

Since the broker is configures with SaSL, I am also providing my username and password. I am currently unaware of why this ERROR occurs. Ive looked around on the internet but there is no clear explanation as to why it would occur with qpid. Any ideas why this ERROR occurs ?

My trustStore file is correct since I have verifies SSL connectivity using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning up the clients logging might give some more trace/debug information. Both the 'regular logging', and 'protocol trace logging' (if it even gets that far) might be useful. See http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-0.22.0/docs/index.html#logging for more details.

To the issue here, where it seems the TCP connection is being cut, the server logs could also perhaps be useful in giving a reason.

You dont mention which server you are using here, but have mentioned ActiveMQ and RabbitMQ in other related questions. Its unclear how far the connection gets, but if the server is RabbitMQ, one potential explanation might also be: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0/issues/47. As mentioned in another answer, this may not matter due to other issues, e.g. I didn't have much success using the JMS client or some other AMQP 1.0 clients against RabbitMQ previously due to an issue I reported which stops them in their tracks when creating consumers and producers: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies. In my case turns out all the libraries/configurations I was using were indeed correct. I contacted the team that manages the broker. Turns out the user I was trying to connect with had some PRIVILEGE issues. As soon as they gave my user the correct rights, I was able to form a successful connection and transmit and receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when receiving this error it was simply because when I was in the office our company proxy was filtering this traffic out when I executed programatically. Using Service Bus Explorer still worked though as it must have picked up machine settings that add the proxy.

We were using a publicly hosted Service Bus so I attempted from my home network without the proxy and everything worked as expected. Using Wireshark or similar program probably would have helped identify this quicker. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

This line shows your error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot send to a non-connected transport.
```

That's saying your connection is configured incorrectly. One thing I see is that your're not referencing the properties in your property file.  For example, 
this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("myFactoryLookup");
Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("myQueueLookup");
```

Should probably be this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("connectionfactory.myFactoryLookup");
Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("queue.myQueueLookup");
```

Comment: The "myFactoryLookup" and "myQueueLookup" lookup values are actually correct. The "connectionfactory." and "queue." prefixes are used by the InitialContextFactory implementation to determine what type of resource is being configured by the property, with the remainder being used as the lookup name.